# Pass XML from C# to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, stored-functions

I'm trying to send XML in following format from C# (DataType string) to SQL Server stored proc:

```
<Content> </Content>
```

There is a space which should get stored as it is in SQL Server column. But it gets stored like `<Content/>`. So in nutshell there is loss of space from c# to SQL Server.

Is there anyway I can avoid this?

Comment: I think your sample code got lost, please edit question so we can help you.

Comment: Mayur put some code. It help peers to understand problem better

Comment: He's losing a space ' ' character in the `<content>` element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two fragments are equivalent; SQL server is just optimizing the XML.

Is there a particular reason you *need* the space in there? If so, you might try `xml:space="preserve"`, like so:

```
<Content xml:space="preserve"> </Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an attribute `xml:space="preserve"`. That helps in "normal" serialization context, I don't know if it will help you in your special context.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use <!CDATA[  ]>?